# syntax issue for sql NOT LIKE

Tags: php, sql

I am stuck and getting errors with following string any ideas please im trying to prevent admin (user) being displayed in results.

```
SELECT * NOT LIKE 'admin' FROM users order by status ASC
```

I have tryed %admin% as well and i am stuck with errors!

Comment: You need a [`WHERE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *  FROM users WHERE user NOT LIKE 'admin' ORDER BY status ASC;
```

Put your where clause after the table name

Comment: It's `WHERE username NOT LIKE 'admin'`.

Comment: I solved it like this

    SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name NOT LIKE '%dmi%' order by status ASC

Comment: @MultiMedia Andrew posted his answer first and they were pretty much identical, I recommend you accept his.

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is wrong, you want to try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username NOT LIKE '%admin%' ORDER BY status ASC
```

Comment: it dosnt change the results what if it is not like but exact is this same?

Comment: It would match the like (since the wildcards can be zero) and wouldn't be included.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `NOT LIKE` if you're doing a comparison against a simple string.  Also, as noted in others' answers your syntax order is mixed up:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username != 'admin' ORDER BY status ASC
```

Cheers